# Seaborn plot showing two labels at the start and end of a month

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I created a plot using `matplotlib` and `seaborn` where the x axis is a date. The x axis current looks like [image] Where I need the label to be in the middle and shown only once.

This is the code I am using to get the plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 8.27))
plot = sns.lineplot(y="Y-Axis", x="date", data=data)
date_form = DateFormatter("%B")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried using `.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=4))` or similar?

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, Thank you very much!